# Override MSTest Parameters in RunSettings file

Tags: azure-pipelines, mstest, vstest, runsettings

I have a .runsettings file that contains the following.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <!-- MSTest adapter -->
    <MSTest>
        <Parallelize>
            <Workers>1</Workers>
            <Scope>ClassLevel</Scope>
        </Parallelize>
    </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

Is it possible to override the Workers and Scope settings from the VsTest@2 task in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines) for the VsTest@2 task only mentions overriding TestRunParameters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and seems that you just have to add your value in the command line, e.g. for overriding only the **workers**:

```
dotnet test --settings:.runsettings -- MSTest.Parallelize.Workers=3
```

or for overriding both **workers** & **scope**

```
dotnet test --settings:.runsettings -- MSTest.Parallelize.Workers=3 MSTest.Parallelize.Scope=MethodLevel
```